# Nexus i9250 constantly reboots, freezes, etc

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, calls, system-freeze

I bought a Nexus a couple of months ago, and sometimes it restarts when I am on a call.

Other times when I am on a call, it freezes, and restarts or unfreezes after a minute.

The phone is not rooted or damaged in any way. I sent it to an official Samsung service center, and they told me that the phone was fine. They also installed new firmware, but the phone still has all the mentioned problems.

Does anyone know an application to monitor the activities of the phone, such as the restarts etc? Something like a log file?

Thanks.